# How do I make a second JS .post call with data from a previous call?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

So, I have a JS .post call that adds a row to a table via a controller action.  It then returns the primary key of that row back to the view.  I need to insert that integer into the data for the second .post call that i need to make to a different controller.

**Updated Javascript**
First is a look at my Javascript:

```
   var result = $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestion/', (data), function (result) {
                                   $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestionChoice/', ({
                                                                 "QuestionId":result,
                                                                 "DisplayText": text,
                                                                 "OrderNumber": order,
                                                                 "is_correct": false}),
                                                                  null, 'application/json');
                }, 'application/json');
```

These are the controller actions that are called:

```
        //
    // POST: /Question/CreateSimpleQuestion

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateSimpleQuestion(Question question)
    {
        question.is_counted = true;
        question.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        db.Questions.Add(question);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(question.QuestionId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Question/CreateSimpleQuestion

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateSimpleQuestionChoice(QuestionChoices choice)
    {
        db.QuestionChoices.Add(choice);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(choice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for jQuery's `post()`? It seems to have examples that demonstrate what you need: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. json is automatically deserialized into a javascript object by the browser. It should be pretty easy to try yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a success handler for the first ajax call (where the key will be available) and in that success handler, you make the second ajax call and you can then pass that key with it.

```
var result = $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestion/', data, function(result) {
    // make your second ajax call here and you can use the result of the first
    // ajax call here
    var dataq = { 
        "QuestionId": result.QuestionId,   // data from first ajax call here
        "DisplayText": text, 
        "OrderNumber": order, 
        "is_correct": false 
    };
    $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestionChoice/', dataq, function(result2) {
        // examine result of second ajax function here
        // code goes here
    }, 'application/json');

}, 'application/json');
```

---

Here's a version with console debug statements embedded in it so you can track it's progress in the debug console, though I personally prefer to just set breakpoints and examine variables.

```
console.log("Position 1");
console.log(data);
var result = $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestion/', data, function(result) {
    // make your second ajax call here and you can use the result of the first
    // ajax call here
    var dataq = { 
        "QuestionId": result.QuestionId,   // data from first ajax call here
        "DisplayText": text, 
        "OrderNumber": order, 
        "is_correct": false 
    };
    console.log("Position 2");
    console.log(dataq);
    $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestionChoice/', dataq, function(result2) {
        // examine result of second ajax function here
        // code goes here
        console.log("Position 3");
        console.log(result2);
    }, 'application/json');

}, 'application/json');
```

Comment: Could you make the ajax call?  I tried that first because i realize that's what i should do, but i kept getting an error about primitive type.

Comment: @schumacherj - I don't know what you want the second ajax call to look like or what the JSON looks like that the first one returns.

Comment: @schumacherj What is the problem with your second ajax call?  That seems like the real issue.

Comment: @schumacherj - I've made a guess at what you're asking for in my latest edit.

Comment: I was having issues with putting the result from the first one into the data for the second ajax call.

Comment: @schumacherj - I think my lastest edits to my answer now show you that.

Comment: @jfriend00 The second controller is not being called, but the first one is.  I don't know the best way to debug javascript. Any advice, pointers?

Comment: @schumacherj - the first thing you do is look in the browser error console or debug console for execution errors in your javascript and follow any leads you find there.

Comment: @schumacherj - also please don't keep changing the code in your question.  You can ADD new versions of the code to the end of your answer if need be, but you should leave the original code that was there that started this whole thing so the whole history is there.  And, just so you know, long lines of code are not legible at all on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have been doing that and it doesn't show any errors.  http://picpaste.com/Capture_1.JPG  It also doesn't show the second controller call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40352/discussion-between-schumacherj-and-jfriend00)

Comment: @schumacherj - If you don't know how to set breakpoints in your JS, put `console.log()` statements into each line of your JS to see where the execution goes (see code I've added to my answer).  This will tell you if the second ajax call is being made.  If so, then the issue is probably on your server-end.  You can also examine the networking tab in the Chrome debugger and watch what is being sent between client/server too.